# Select all messages but not if the subject id is the same

Tags: vb.net, linq

i am trying to select all the messages written from a certain from_id but only display the latest message with the same subject id. for example my messaging table looks like this:

```
Id
From_ID
To_ID
Subject
Subject_ID
Date
[Content]
Percentage
```

each message is created with a unique ID, if the message is in the same message chain i.e. a follow on message the subject id is the same as the message ID. i have the code to select by the current user that's logged in :

```
Dim query = From p In db.Messages Select p Where p.From_ID = Userid
```

But i am unsure how to group it by the newest message with the same subject id.
thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Visual Basic expert, but you can use `Group By` to group the returned messages by the `SubjectID` and then just select the latest message from each of the groups using `Select`. The syntax looks roughly like this:

```
Dim q = From p In db.Messaes
        Where p.From_ID = Userid
        Group By Subject = p.Subject_ID 
        Into Messages = Group
        Select ...
```

The `...` bit needs to be replaced with a subquery that returns the latest message from messages in the current group (available in `Messages`).

Comment: im not entirely sure how i would construct the sub query as when using the 'Messages' it doesn't show the fields in the table

Comment: @Houlahan - `Messages` is a collection of messages, so you need a nested query - for example, sort `Messages` by the date and then take the first one.

Comment: "Dim q = From p In db.Messages Where p.From_ID = Userid Group By Subject = p.Subject_ID Into Messages = Group From p In Messages Order By p.Date Descending Select p" i tried that but didn't group the messages am i on the right track or is this the total wrong way